# how to toggle between the running exe files using c#.net code on button click?

Tags: file, toggle, exe

sir i want to know that how could i navigate/toggle between the different exe files using c#.net code on my .net application on the button click event..basically i want to do toggling between the current and previously opened running exe files..im able to run an exe file on my .net application but not able to provide an option for opening the previously running exe file...on the whole i want to provide a facility same as we are having in the OS windows that we could toggle between the applications on the taskbar menu
how could i do the same in the c#.net application using c# code.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not sure if I got you correctly but if you want to invoke a new exe on any event use:-

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo f = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\\windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe",
"C:\\windows\\system32\\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " +
fileName.TrimEnd (null));

try
{
// Pass the ProcessStartInfo object to the Start function.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (f);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (ex.ToString ());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code..but exe is appearing on the seperate window can u provide me the solution for embedding the exe on the panel of my .netprogram using c#code. i dont want to execute the exe on the seperate window i want to execute it within the panel.